# logging into DB with log4net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, logging, log4net

I use `log4net` for logging errors in my project. I want to log messages into DB (`SQL Server`) so I added `AdoNetAppender` but it does not work (other appenders work fine, connection string is correct). 
What can be wrong?

Comment: Too bad I can't remotely view your code through telepathic signals.

Comment: As others have said, you need to show some code, specifically your configuration file and connection strings in order for anyone to really give you a helping hand here. [Please see this page for examples of log4net configurations.](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

Comment: Lots of things could be wrong.  Configuration being one.  Do you have anything like `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` anywhere in your code?  Check out [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: @JamesR. That's a good point but probably not the case because he says his other appenders work fine. He also says connection string is correct, so it's almost definitely a config error in his AdoNetAppender. Log4net is a fail-stop/best effort system, which is a good thing, but also unfortunately a bad thing (for debugging).

Comment: Yes, I thought of that after I made that comment.  Look very closely at your table, too.  Make sure all of the columns are correct.  Perhaps simplify the problem as well by simplifying the config as much as possible.  I.e., maybe just try one single column like the log message.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should add some details. AdoNetAppender worked before. It stopped to work after addind some code in my project but I haven't changed logging system so I can't imagine what part of new code broke DB logging (because of it I can't give same peaces of code). And as AdoNetAppender worked before I make a decision that config file is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to create a bare-bones example project.  This works.  Perhaps you should try making it work.

Create an empty console application project.  Add a reference to log4net.
C# Code:

```
using log4net;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace Litter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            LogManager.GetLogger("default").Info("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Config file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <configuration>
>   <configSections>
>     <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
>   </configSections>
>   <startup> 
>     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
>   </startup>
>   <log4net>
>     <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
>       <bufferSize value="1"/>
>       <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
>       <connectionString value="data source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Litter;integrated security=True;"/>
>       <commandText value="INSERT INTO Logs ([Message]) VALUES (@message)"/>
>       <parameter>
>         <parameterName value="@message"/>
>         <dbType value="String"/>
>         <size value="2000"/>
>         <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
>           <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
>         </layout>
>       </parameter>
>     </appender>
>     <root>
>       <level value="DEBUG"/>
>       <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
>     </root>
>   </log4net>
> </configuration>
> ```

Database table:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs]([Message] [nvarchar](2000) NOT NULL)
> GO
> ```

That's about as simple as it gets.  If you can make this work, then I'd start looking very closely at your app's AdoNetAppender configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. The problem was in DB. I just have to set the `RowGuid` property as true.